# Show my current cursor position as a current line and current column?

Tags: c#, winforms, cursor

I am working on Windows Forms application that uses a `RichtextBox`, `Menustrip` and many more controls.

I have done some work but can't get it to work. When my mouse cursor moves in RichTextBox I want to change change the position automatically, like that on simple notepad.

My bit coding is....

**I want it so when my mouse cursor moves it changes the dynamic position on my status bar**

```
private void sizeToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{        
    int line = richTextBox1.GetLineFromCharIndex(richTextBox1.SelectionStart);
    int column = richTextBox1.SelectionStart - richTextBox1.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(line);
    toolStripStatusLabel5.Text ="Line"+" "+ line.ToString();
    toolStripStatusLabel6.Text = " Column" + " " + line.ToString();
    toolStripStatusLabel3.Text= Cursor.Position.ToString(); // where is my mouse cursor at this Time like that x and y cordinate 330,334
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

show your line every time when press the enter key.
code is mention below:::----

```
private void Key_Down(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyData == Keys.Enter)
    {
        int line = richTextBox1.GetLineFromCharIndex(richTextBox1.SelectionStart);
        int column = richTextBox1.SelectionStart - richTextBox1.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(line);

        toolStripStatusLabel5.Text = "Line" + " " + line.ToString();
        toolStripStatusLabel6.Text = " Column" + " " + column.ToString();
        toolStripStatusLabel3.Text = Cursor.Position.ToString(); // where is my mouse cursor at this Time like that x and y cordinate 330,334
        Update();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could subscribe to the `RichTextBox` `MouseMove` event to update the `ToolStrip` label with the current mouse position

Example:

```
private void richTextBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    toolStripStatusLabel3.Text = string.Format("X={0}, Y={1}", e.X, e.Y);
}
```

Or if you want it to show the position reletive to the `RichTextBox` you can use the `Location` from the `MouseEventArgs`, this will return the position inside the `RichTextBox` (topleft of textbox = 0,0)

```
private void richTextBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    toolStripStatusLabel3.Text = string.Format("X={0}, Y={1}", e.Location.X, e.Location.Y);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to update position automatically, you should use MouseMove event from richtextbox instead. While you are moving your mouse it is always updating. Also,  "MouseEventArgs e" from MouseMove call can give you the cursor position inside the richtextbox.

Comment: can you share about the MouseMove coding

Answer (score 1):

I have done with the help of StackoverFlow and sweetly user(programmer).
Thanks for reply. My code is

```
private void richTextBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            int line = richTextBox1.GetLineFromCharIndex(richTextBox1.SelectionStart);
            int column = richTextBox1.SelectionStart - richTextBox1.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(line);

            toolStripStatusLabel5.Text = "Line" + " " + line.ToString();
            toolStripStatusLabel6.Text = " Column" + " " + line.ToString();
            toolStripStatusLabel3.Text = Cursor.Position.ToString(); // where is my mouse cursor at this Time like that x and y cordinate 330,334
            Update();

        }

    }
```